# IIS ftp server issue from command line

Tags: iis, firewall, ftp, windows-command-prompt

I'm trying to config an ftp server on IIS (Windows Server 2008 R2)

I configured basic authentication with read,write permissions for a user and no SSL

I also opened port 21 on server firewall

then from server cmd, i opened localhost, and after login i tried "ls" command and it has been successful

then i tried from a client with FileZilla and it works

here the log :

```
Stato:  Connessione a X.X.X.X:Y...
Stato:  Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Comando:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Stato:  Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Comando:    USER **********
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   331 Password required for **********.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Comando:    PASS **********
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   230 User logged in.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Comando:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Stato:  Accesso effettuato
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  Measured latency of 60 ms
Stato:  Lettura elenco cartelle...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend()
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
Trace:    state = 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Stato:  Elenco cartella di "/" completato
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

but from a client cmd, trying "ls" command i receive:

```
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

and from another one after "open [ip] [port]" command i don't receive anything

I think that's a firewall problem and has to do with active/passive mode but why with FileZilla it works fine?

What should I do to make it work from the command line?

**EDIT**
I also tried to disable windows firewall but problem persists

but if is it, why FileZilla works ? can't i use active mode with default ports instead of passive mode with dynamics ports?

Comment: I know you don't have rep yet, but don't respond to answers within your question. Edit your question appropriately with additional info. Respond directly to answers with comments if need be (when you have enough rep). (also, no need to add things like "thanks")

Answer (score 0):

it's the firewall, the dynamci port is blocked

try this:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp 49152 16383 persistent
```

this opens all of the FTP dynamic ports